# mongodb - How to increment a field conditionally based on value of another field in same collection?

Tags: mongodb

How to modify the query below to increment conditionally

- by 1 if `published: false`
- by *a_Variable* if `published: true`

where `published` is another field in the same collection `posts`

```
  await db.collection('posts').updateOne(
    {_id: postId},
    {$inc: {rep: a_Variable } //increment by 1 if published: false
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  "_id": postId
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      rep: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: ["$published",false]
          },
          then: {
            $add: ["$rep",1]
          },
          else: {
            $add: ["$rep",a_Variable]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EMjwEf49-LL)